# How to override my general css link styles

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this general style in my CSS:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
  color: #green;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: 500; 
}
```

Now I am trying to override a link with the following:

```
.post-title a {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post-title .level-one a {
    color: #red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post-title .level-two a {
    color: #orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}


<p class=""><a href="" class="post-title level-one">Hello world</a></p>
```

My CSS is not applied, the text color is green and it is underlined.

How can i fix this?

Comment: `.post-title .level-one` remove the space between the classes so it's `.post-title.level-one`. The space is having it look for an element with the class `.level-one` *inside* an element with the class `.post-title`.

Comment: In addition to @DrewKennedy's comment, you may need to override also the `a:visited`, `a:link` , `a:active`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I did that, but the color is still green and underlined.

Comment: On an unrelated note, color names (such as `green` or `orange`) don't use the `#` (that's only for colors in hexadecimal form, such as `#333333`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the same pseudo-selectors as in the rule you want to override, plus if the `a` links themselves have those classes (which I didn't see at first), you have to append them to the `a` links *without* a space in between

```
a:link.post-title , a:visited.post-title , a:active.post-title  { .......
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in CSS separate elements. So

```
.post-title .level-one {  ...  }
```

is looking for an element with the class `level-one` that's *inside* another element of class `post-title`.

In your case,

```
.post-title .level-one a {  ...  }
```

is actually looking for a `<a>` tag *inside* an element with class `level-one`, *inside* a parent with class `post-title`!

---

This:

```
.post-title.level-one {  ...  }
```

looks for an element with both the class `post-title` *and* `level-one`.

So, as [Drew Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4204026/drew-kennedy) commented, just remove the spaces in your override, and everything should be fine!

```css
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.post-title.level-one {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <a href="" class="wrong-class"> Greenie! </a>
</p>
<p>
    <a href="" class="post-title level-one"> Orangy! </a>
</p>
```